# Spring DM compatibility with Spring 4.*

Tags: spring, osgi

An OSGi based application I have inherited uses the org.springframework.osgi.extender bundle version 1.2.1.
Currently, I am using Java 1.7 and Spring 2.5.6.

I recently installed Java 8 on my machine and the org.springframework.osgi.extender bundle no longer launches due to the following error :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.springframework.osgi.extender [21].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2196)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
        at org.apache.felix.shell.impl.StartCommandImpl.execute(StartCommandImpl.java:114)
        at org.apache.felix.shell.impl.Activator$ShellServiceImpl.executeCommand(Activator.java:249)
        at org.apache.felix.shell.tui.Activator$ShellTuiRunnable.run(Activator.java:184)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create ConcurrentHashMap - neither JDK 1.5 nor backport-concurrent available on the classpath
        at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMap(CollectionFactory.java:229)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener.<init>(ContextLoaderListener.java:332)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4336)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2141)
        ... 6 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create ConcurrentHashMap - neither JDK 1.5 nor backport-concurrent available on the classpath
```

I was going to upgrade Spring to 4.0.3, but I notice that the org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMap() method has been deprecated and removed.

Will Spring DM be upgraded to work with Spring 4.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Spring DM be upgraded to work with Spring 4.*?

No. Spring discontinued to support OSGi since 4.0 and it was the right decision. The concept of Spring does not fit into OSGi.

See http://blog.osgi.org/2014/09/how-should-i-use-guicespringblueprint.html

Comment: I don't agree with "The concept of Spring does not fit into OSGi". And, I would call the end of support by spring an unrational "management decision".

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in older posts Spring DM is now an Eclipse project, Gemini Blueprint: 
https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/
Here is an relevant forum thread which indicates that Spring 4 support is on the way:
 https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/642416/
Snapshots can be downloaded here:
https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/gemini-blueprint-snapshots

If you are looking for the Spring 4 OSGi bundles, they are continued by [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) and can be downloaded here:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/

Answer (score 0):

Spring DM moved and is now Gemini Blueprint: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.gemini.blueprint

From the reference: https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/eclipse-migration.html

> In late 2009, as a member of the Gemini project proposal, SpringSource
>   contributed Spring Dynamic Modules (also known as Spring OSGi) project
>   to the Eclipse Foundation. Spring DM v2 code base has been moved to
>   Eclipse.org along with its issue tracker and forum. The project became
>   dual licensed under Apache License and EPL. While the name has
>   changed, the code and its functionality remained the same. Existing
>   Spring DM applications can be easily migrated to Eclipse Gemini
>   Blueprint as mentioned in the migration guide. While the project name
>   has changed (to Eclipse Gemini Blueprint) and significant efforts have
>   been made to reflect this in the project documentation and resources,
>   there might be places that we have missed; if you find any, please
>   report them to us.

You can use Gemini Blueprint with Spring 3.2, there is no support for 4.0 and as far as i know, its not yet planned for the 2.0 Release of Gemini Blueprint.